# Pesach: Shira Taamim?

Tags: passover, torah-reading, beshalach, trop-cantillation

I cannot recall, find or ask anyone who remembers 100% if, when we read Shiras Hayam (from Beshalach) on the 7th day of Pesach, we do so using the regular taamim (Trupp) or the Taamey Shira, the same ones we use on Shabbos Shira.

Can anyone answer this (please be sure)? — and a source would really be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello boruch and welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Thank you for bringing your question here.  I look forward to seeing you around the site.

Comment: I'll second @MonicaCellio's welcome and merely add that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. A question like this one, in particular, would normally be addressed to a synagogue's own rabbi or other authority.

Comment: Note also that customs may vary among synagogues and communities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Nitei Gavriel*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=109), the custom is to sing with the *taamei shira*. (This seems to be his intention, although the statement is quite vague.) He quotes this from *Minhagei Frankfurt* as well as *Hosafos HaYaavetz*. He also lists some of the customs that pertain to which *pesukim* to apply the tune to, etc.

Comment: on the next siman (about which pesukim and the pesukim before) he says pretty clearly, Btaam hayadua :)